# PIP install my OS project

Tags: python, pip

I've created an open source project and tried to register it with PIP so people can use pip install.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get it work.  Here are the commands I've tried:

Created a setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='AyeGotchoPayCheque',
    version='.9',
    description='Payment Gateway Interface',
    author='Rico Cordova',
    author_email='rico.cordova@rocksolidbox.com',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/ayegotchopaycheque-sig/',
    packages=['ayegotchopaycheque', 'ayegotchopaycheque'],
)
```

Then I used the command `python setup.py register` and answered the questions.

I've tried several other solutions and can't seem to get this working.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:
It seems I've successfully registered my project with the wrong `name=AyeGotchoPayChecque`, note the extra "c".  How can I "unregister" this project and re-register with the correct name?

Comment: FYI:  You are registering with PyPI, not `pip`.  `pip` is the command line program used to install python modules that downloads from PyPI.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you couldn't get to work, so I made a guess in the answer I posted.  Let me know if I did not answer what you wanted to know and I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "unregister", log into PyPI and go to the account page for the package you registered, then click on the "Remove this package completely" button.  Then, you can reregister with the correct name.  Don't forget to upload the project as well.  I prefer to do it at the same time that I register:

```
python setup.py egg_info -RDb "" sdist register upload
```

Each time you upgrade your package's version number, re-run the above code, and PyPI will keep all versions of your package on the package's website.